# How do I implement the <router-outlet> directive in Nativescript to show child routes?

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-nativescript

I have been working with Nativescript with Angular 2 and Typescript and understand there are two options for the router outlet.  The original angular `<router-outlet>` directive which can be used to show children routes of a component, and the `<page-router-outlet>` which is specific to nativescript routing.  I have been using the latter and attempting to use the `<router-outlet>` directive but find that it acts the same.  I want for example this scenario.

parent.component.html

```
<StackLayout>
<Button [nsRouterLink]="['/accounts/edit-account']"><Button>
<Button [nsRouterLink]="['/accounts/new-account']"><Button>
</StackLayout>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This has two buttons with nativescript nsRouterlink directive.  I want the buttons to remain while the router-outlet updates with the child information. 
here are the routes.

module.routing.ts

```
const Routes: Routes = [
  { path: "accounts", children: [
    {path: "", component: ParentComponent },
    { path: "new-account", component: ChildOneComponent}, 
    { path: "edit-account", component: ChildTwoomponent},
  ]  
},

];
```

The problem is when I attempt this it replaces the entire screen without leaving the buttons in place as would do the `<page-router-outlet>` directive.

I've even followed this [documentation by Nativescript](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation) and the example does not act as the documentation declares.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the Nativescript Documentation again works ok. The solution in general is in the routing to change from

```
const Routes: Routes = [
  { path: "accounts", children: [
    {path: "", component: ParentComponent },
    { path: "new-account", component: ChildOneComponent}, 
    { path: "edit-account", component: ChildTwoomponent},
  ]  
},

];
```

to

```
const Routes: Routes = [
  { path: "accounts", component: ParentComponent, children: [
    {path: "", redirectTo: "/accounts/new-account", pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: "new-account", component: ChildOneComponent}, 
    { path: "edit-account", component: ChildTwoomponent},
  ]  
},

];
```

Finding this I have a new issue that I will post in a different question and link to this answer later.